# How can I draw circle image at the place where camera is directed to?? [arcore]

Tags: android, kotlin, augmented-reality, arcore, sceneform

[Ikea app screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QlwDG.jpg)

arFragment planeRenderer renders a plane filled with dots. I want to get rid of them and make planeRenderer draw a circle in the centre of the fragment, transformed according to surface (like ikea App). How can I do it using Sceneform?

Comment: Could you share your code and proposal until now?

Comment: Tried to do something like this:

Comment: val sampler: Texture.Sampler = Texture.Sampler.builder()
            .setMinFilter(Texture.Sampler.MinFilter.LINEAR)
            .setMagFilter(Texture.Sampler.MagFilter.LINEAR)
            .setWrapMode(Texture.Sampler.WrapMode.CLAMP_TO_EDGE).build()

Comment: val trigrid: CompletableFuture<Texture> = Texture.builder()
            .setSource(requireContext(), R.drawable.circle)
            .setSampler(sampler).build()

Comment: _arFragment?.arSceneView?.planeRenderer?.material?.thenAcceptBoth(trigrid) { material, texture ->
            material.setTexture(
                PlaneRenderer.MATERIAL_TEXTURE,
                texture
            )
        }

Comment: Now im not sure question is valid, cause as I see sometimes plane visualization doest not renders, while I am able to tap somewhere and place an Object there. Also, sometimes plane visualization is so small I have no idea how to place circle there.
Seems like Sceneform was archived for objective reasons